# How to run a separate script in Github repo in Github Actions

Tags: r, github, github-actions

trying to implement a workflow on Github actions that will run a test script with the functions of my package and ideally print/export out the results. I am new to the YAML syntax and would appreciate any help.

This is the workflow I currently have:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - master

name: Test-Script

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }} 

    name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }}) 

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false 
      matrix:
        config:
          - {os: windows-latest, r: 'release'}
          - {os: macOS-latest, r: 'release'} 

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2 

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1 
        with:
          r-version: ${{ matrix.config.r }}

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v1

      - name: Test against test script
        run: |
          /R/test_script.R #file path in repo
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

I get the erorr: Error: Error: unexpected '/' in "/". I have tried multiple adjustments but always get that error or another saying that the file cannot be found. I would also like to print out/export out the results but I do not know how to do so.

Would appreciate any help please. Thank you.

Comment: I'd first try changing your `run:` line to `run: Rscript test_script.R`

Comment: `name`, `strategy`, and `steps` needs to be indented on the same level as `build`. Also, as you're saying you're just starting out, I'd recommend removing everything with the matrix and try a single job first. Once that works, add the matrix again.

Comment: @Matt I got the following error: Error: unexpected symbol in "Rscript test_script.R"

Comment: @rethab okay, I did that but i always end up getting an error at the `run:` line, where theres an unexpected symbol or that they cant find the file

Comment: Please show your `run` step as it is rather than with that comment. A good question on SO is one that could be copied by another person and the same problem would manifest -- otherwise it's difficult to guess what might be there.

Comment: Is your repository public? if yes, could you share it so we could make a fork to try finding a solution? :)